# Laravel's Eloquent hasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there possible to do a hasManyThrough getting user's country id from a Many to Many pivot table (country_user) ? something like

```
countries
   id - integer
   name - string

users
   id - integer
   name - string

posts
   id - integer
   user_id - integer
   title - string

country_user
    user_id - integer
    country_id - integer
```

Comment: You have many-to-many relationship. you don't need `hasManyThrough` here. You just use `belongsToMany` to specify many-to-many relationship.
docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: so how can I get all posts from user's country? I don't get it..

Comment: Ohh you mean to get user's countries with having only posts? You can get like this: `$post->user->countries` this will give you a list of user`s countries. In your case, you use many-to-many on countries.

Comment: damn, so twisted :) I couldn't figure it out. thanks

Comment: or having `country_id` and `user_id`: 

`$country = Country::whereId($countryId)->whereHas('user', function($q) use ($userId) { $q->whereId($userId)->with('posts'); })->with('user')->first();`

This will get the country object by having countryId and userId with user and posts.

`$country->user->posts`